# How to join IdentityUser in my custom class CreatorId

Tags: domain-driven-design, abp

I have following class

```
public class Comment : FullAuditedEntity<Guid>
{ 
public string Text { get; set; } 
public Guid PostID { get; set; }  
public IdentityUser Creator { get; set; }
}
```

On OnModelCreating() function I use follwing code,

```
builder.Entity<Comment>(b =>
    {
        b.ToTable(Comments",  DatabaseConsts.DbSchema);
        b.ConfigureByConvention();
        b.Property(x => x.Text).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
        b.Property(x => x.CreatorId).IsRequired();
        b.HasOne<IdentityUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatorId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        b.HasIndex(x => x.CreatorId); 
    });
```

But while running the migration, it shows following warning, and it creates new property called 'CreatorId1'

> The foreign key property 'Comment.CreatorId1' was created in shadow
> state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'CreatorId'
> exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used
> for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated
> primary key type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships for
> information on mapping relationships in EF Core.

I need to map CreatorId, which available through FullAuditedEntity should be mapped with Creator property. How to do that. The new column CreatorId1 must not be created.

Answer (score 0):

For FullAuditedEntity, ABP does it itself, you don't need to do it. `b.ConfigureByConvention();` done in the method.